# Creating a list for formula in R for raking

Tags: r, list, formula, survey

I am trying to generate a list to match the required parameter for the `rake` function in the [`survey` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf). The parameter in question is called `sample.margins` and in the documentation (page 27) it's described as requiring `list of formulas or data frames describing sample margins, which must not contain missing values`

I am using the following list:

```
[[1]]
~age_bucket
<environment: 0x125f741c8>

[[2]]
~educ_bucket
```

The list is created as:

```
  rake_sample_margins <- lapply(1:length(column_names), function(x) {
                                                                  as.formula(paste0("~", column_names))
                                                                })

  rake_sample_margins[[length(rake_sample_margins) + 1]] <- as.formula(~educ_bucket)
```

So `~educ_bucket` is created after the `lapply` whereas `~age_bucket` is created by iterating through the `column_names` vector (which in this case contains only that string `age_bucket`.

When I run my code using this list for the parameter of the rake function, I get this error:

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  object 'educ_bucket' not found
```

Even though when I examine the correlating dataframe in another parameter it is indeed there (as the 2nd element of that list of data frames):

```
[[2]]
            educ_bucket       FREQ
1:               groupA      .002
2:               groupB      .08
```

I've been told that the list of formulae must exactly match a column in the data frame in the list of dataframes passed, but I believe I am matching this. Is there something else about this I'm missing? Also, I notice I have an irregularity with the list. The first formula includes: `<environment: 0x125f741c8>` underneath the formula when printed out, whereas the second does not. What, if anything, does that mean?

Comment: Even-though this is not related to your question, please note the `lapply` seems to be working only because you have one item in `column_names`. You could write it like this instead:`lapply(column_names, function(x) {as.formula(paste0("~", x))})`

Comment: @HubertL thank you for your comment. Can you tell me why this lapply would not work in the case that column_names had more than 1 element?

Comment: Just try `column_names <- c('a','b','c');lapply(1:length(column_names) , function(x) {as.formula(paste0("~", column_names)) })`

Comment: @helloB could you please provide a minimal reproducible example?  `?rake` gives you fake data that should be enough to regenerate your problem with an example that others can replicate. it also provides an example `sample.margins` table